# Can I copy a field value from sub-task to the parent issue

Tags: groovy, jira

I am looking for a method to update a parent issue custom field with data from a sub-task when I transition a sub-task. (perhaps some post-function or a script listener)
For example:
Each of the Subtasks will have a Multi User Picker field.
If Subtask-1 has values User-1, User-2, Subtask-2 has values User-2, User-3 then the parent custom field should have values of User-1, User-2, User-3

Is this possible using only the script runner plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can easily implement a post function script that takes care of this. After that you can add this post function to the desired transition of your subtask's workflow.

Documentation available [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/custom-workflow-functions.html) and some [relevant examples here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/recipes/workflow/postfunctions/set-issue-attributes.html).